# Why does my browser receive no data when OutputStream.flush() is called?

Tags: java, file-io, outputstream

I have a servlet which just read a file and send it to the browser.
The file is readen correctly, but on OutputStream.flush(), the browser receive no data.

Firefox says :
"Corrupted Content Error
 The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.". Firebug shows the status "Aborted".

IE open or save an empty file.
I tried little or big files.

The code is :

```
    /** 
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Use a ServletOutputStream because we may pass binary information
        response.reset();
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        // Get the file to view
        String file = request.getParameter("path");

        // Get and set the type and size of the file
        String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file);
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        long fileSize = (new File(file)).length();
        response.setHeader("Content-Length:", "" + fileSize);

        File f = new File(file);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+f.getName()); 
        response.setContentLength((int) fileSize);

        // Return the file
        try {
            returnFile(file, out, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(AffichageItemsServlet.class).error("", e);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // Send the contents of the file to the output stream
    public static void returnFile(String filename, OutputStream out, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            byte[] buff = new byte[8* 1024];

            int nbRead = 0;
            while ((nbRead = fis.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) !=-1) {
                out.write(buff, 0, nbRead);
            }

            out.flush();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The response is sent on "out.flush".

Any idea ?

Comment: Does the getParameter("path") returns absolute path of file name or just filename only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, remove this line (you call setContentLength() below that):

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length:", "" + fileSize);
```

Also, you might try moving the `getOutputStream()` call to just before you start using the stream.

Comment: Thanks ! Removing this line :

        response.setHeader("Content-Length:", "" + fileSize);
solved my problem.